# Proving Frobenius Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a frobenius subgroup of $G$
>
> $H \leq G$ is a frobenius subgroup if $H \cap tHt^{-1} = \{ 1 \}$, for all $ t \notin H$.
>
> $f : H \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a class function if $f(s) = f(tst^{-1}) , \forall t,s \in H$.
>
> Let $N$ be the set of elements of $G$ not conjugate to any element of $H$.

I have to show the following:

> $1.)$ Let $f$ be a class function on $H$. Let $\tilde{f}$ be the unique class function on $G$ which extends $H$ and takes the value $f(1)$ on $N$. Show that $\tilde{f} = Ind_{H}^{G} (f) - f(1) \psi$, where $Ind_{H}^{G}(f)(s) = \frac{1}{|H|} \sum_{\substack{t \in G \\ tst^{-1} \in H}} f(tst^{-1})$, and $\psi$ is the character of the permutation representation of $G$ acting on $G/H$.
>
> $2.)$ Show that for class functions $f_{1} ,f_{2}$ on $H$, $\langle f_{1} , f_{2} \rangle_{H} = \langle \tilde{f_{1}} , \tilde{f_{2}} \rangle_{G}$, where $\langle f_{1} , f_{2} \rangle_{H} = \frac{1}{|H|} \sum_{h \in H} f_{1}(h^{-1}) f_{2}(h)$.
>
> $3.)$ If $f$ is an irreducible character of $H$ then $\tilde{f}(1) \geq 0$ and $\tilde{f}$ is an integral linear combination of the irreducible characters of $G$.

Comments

> I was really stuck on getting a formula for $\psi$ in $(1)$.
>
> To show $(2)$, we need to show that $\frac{1}{|H|} \sum_{h \in H} f_{1}(h^{-1}) f_{2}(h) = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \tilde{f_{1}}(g^{-1}) \tilde{f_{2}}(g) = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} (Ind_{H}^{G} (f_{1}) - f_{1}(1) \psi)(g^{-1}) (Ind_{H}^{G} (f_{2}) - f_{2}(1) \psi)(g)$. But nothing seems obvious to me.
>
> To show $3.)$, we have to show that $Ind_{H}^{G} (f)(1)  \geq f(1) \psi(1) \iff \frac{|G|}{|H|} f(1) \geq f(1) \psi(1) \iff \frac{|G|}{|H|} \geq \psi(1)$, but I believe $\psi(1) = \frac{|G|}{|H|}$ so we are good. Note we can divide by $f(1)$, because $f(1) = n_{i}$ which the dimension of the corresponding representation which is positive. However, I don't know how to show $\tilde{f}$ is an integral linear combination of the irreducible characters of $G$, it is certainly a linear combination since the irreducible characters are an orthonormal basis of the class functions of $G$.
>
> Any constructive feedback and/or suggestions/hints/answers are welcome.